# How to call a function from different component using React with Redux Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am trying to call a function from a component when some `Field` receives a different value.

For example, I have a component 'FieldSelections' where the user can select values from a `Field`. When a value is selected I want to call a function `fieldValueChanged` from a different component called `MyComponent`.

This is what I've tried

```
class FieldSelections extends Component {
  handleChange = () => {
    this.child.fieldValueChanged();
  }
}
```

...

```
  <Field
      name='field'
      component={renderSelectField}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <FieldArray
      name='fieldArray'
      component={MyComponent}
      ref={ obj => this.child = obj; }>
  </FieldArray>
```

MyComponent.js

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  fieldValueChanged = () => {
    console.log('Do Something')
  }
}
```

But it is giving this error:

> _this.child.fieldValueChanged is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share an example on:- http://codesandbox.io

Comment: It should be this.props.fieldValueChanged(); but not this.child.fieldValueChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  handleChange = () => {
        this.child.fieldValueChanged();
  }
```

To

```
  handleChange = () => {
      this.props.fieldValueChanged();
  }
```

Make sure you pass fieldValueChanged() as props to  FieldSelections component when call it in MyComponent like

In your MyComponent when you call FieldSelections

```
   <FieldSelections fieldValueChanged={this.fieldValueChanged} />
```

Comment: The problem is that `MyComponent` is used just to return data and I'm not calling `FieldSelections` inside it.

Comment: @Valip That's how you need to implement to access this.props.fieldValueChanged(); in FieldSelections component. MyComponent should call FieldSelections. There is no other way you can access fieldValueChanged in FieldSelections component